# Treating a sick Angel fish

Tags: aquarium

My Angel fish has two pink growths on either side where her dorsal fins were.
The fins are now missing.
The guy in the fish shop said it looks like a bacterial infection and sold me some Erythromycin.  He said I should
treat the entire tank (I have 2 discus
and two Corey’s) but I read online that
only the affected fish should be treated and in a separate quarantine tank.
Please advise.

Comment: General: you can follow both ways. For separate treatment you need less medication because of less water volume. Also be aware that a filter would clean the water from the treatment, so you would pause the filtering. If the fish's skin is fully healed again, it will be more resistant against bacteria again. So if you treat full tank: all of this bacteria will got rid of. If you treat your fish separate and the skin is whole again, it will resist the bacteria in the tank. In general bacteria infection are a sympthom of bad water quality. Research or ask how to maintain your tank to increase :)

Comment: What @Allerleirauh said. Do a water sample test first, then add the medicine to the main tank and pause the filtration. After the treatment, you should change your water (suggest 1/3rd or less at a time), and clean the filters in the removed tank water to remove any large debris. Then get your ammonia and pH levels under control and monitor.